# Как выполнить js-скрипт после асинхронной загрузки другого скрипта?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь добавить на страницу виджет публикации ссылок от ВКонтакте. При обычном подключении

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://vk.com/js/api/share.js?93" charset="windows-1251"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(VK.Share.button()); 
</script>
```

...страница очень долго загружается. Рассудил, что нужно подключать файл ассинхронно. Но тогда я не знаю и не отслежу когда оно загрузится, чтобы вызвать следующий скрипт. Как это решается?

Comment: Возможно ответ будет тут "Внешние скрипты, порядок исполнения"
http://learn.javascript.ru/external-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Правильное решение:**

```js
function loadScriptStatic(url, callback, charset)
{
 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.type = 'text/javascript';
 script.charset = charset || 'windows-1251';

 if(script.readyState)// IE
 {
  script.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
   if(script.readyState === 'loaded' || script.readyState === 'complete')
   {
    script.onreadystatechange = null;
    callback();
   }
  };
 }
 else //остальные
 {
  script.onload = function(){callback()};
 }
 script.src = url;
 document.head.appendChild(script);
}

loadScriptStatic('https://vk.com/js/api/share.js?93',
    function(){document.write(VK.Share.button())});
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно синхронно отрендерить кнопку в шаблон (вроде `<script type="text/html"></script>'`) в конце `body`, а потом по `DOMContentLoaded` перенести туда, куда хотите.